# Scrapy error (Unsupported url scheme javascript)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new in Scrapy. Currently using Scraping 1.8. I am able to **scrape** the data and output it into json file with following command.

```
scrapy crawl jokes -o data.json
```

Unfortunately there is some error occured as follow. How can i fix all those error?

```
import scrapy

class JokesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jokes'

    start_urls = [
        'http://www.laughfactory.com/jokes/family-jokes'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for joke in response.xpath("//div[@class='jokes']"):
            yield {
                'joke_text': joke.xpath(".//div[@class='joke-text']/p").get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a/@href").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

**Error 1:** (can be fix by turning `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` to false but I don't think that is correct way)

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET javascript:/robots.txt>: Unsupported URL scheme 'javascript': no handler available for that scheme
```

**Error 2:**

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET javascript:void(0)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\project\scrapycourse\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\project\scrapycourse\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 512, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\project\scrapycourse\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\project\scrapycourse\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\user\desktop\project\scrapycourse\virtual_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 70, in download_request
    (scheme, self._notconfigured[scheme]))
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme 'javascript': no handler available for that scheme
```

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very last page result page (currently #13) contains this HTML:

```
<li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0)">NEXT</a></li>
```

as you can see there is `class="next"` and `a` with `href`. I recommend to rewrite your XPath expression a bit (check if there is `http` part):

```
next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='next']/a[contains(@href, 'http')]/@href").get()
```